# New manager relocating employee for corner office?

Tags: new-manager

I start a new position as manager with my current company/different program next week. This is a new formal position and formal leadership On site has been non-existent for a few years. I was told today that leadership is planning to have the employee who is currently in “the corner office” which has always been occupied by the leader of the program, to move so that I can move in.

I feel like this is instantly creating some weirdness on the team for a few extra square feet of office space. My original instinct was to decline, and still is. But then I think of us all crammed into an office for a meeting, where a few extra square feet help..

What are your opinions/experiences/feedback for this type of situation? Is the potential strife of moving offices worth the few extra square feet and occupying the traditional corner office?

Comment: There is very insufficient information provided for a proper evaluation. We do not know what "a few" means, the layout of the floor (including walls, windows, doors), the number of employees, ... This decision has to be done on the spot, involving all people.

Comment: @virolino Why involving all people?

Comment: Seconded that we can't answer this, but for different reasons. This is purely a company culture and regional culture issue. Leadership is trying to make it clear that you're the boss. With my cultural background, I see nothing (particularly) wrong with wasting a few hours to establish that.

Comment: Because the change has the potential to upset more than the "corner office" employee. Getting the people involved in decisions transforms the manager into leader.

Comment: New mgr, did you consider that the person in the corner office was already told that it would be a temporary assignment? "Hey, this office is open until we find a new manager, but you can use it until then!"

Comment: @Mars: you do not not know a lot of details about that place, like all of us. If the floor is already too crowded, then the over-crowding will get worse. Maybe that guy also need to organize meetings with people. Maybe instead of a big MR for the boss, 2 small offices and a big meeting room are the better alternative. But all this is speculation, both from my side and yours.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. It’sa small team of about 10 employees. The offices are small with limited meeting space. Culture up to this point has been to just have the meetings in the corner office with everyone packed in. I was given the office next door when I met the team a few weeks ago - there was no indication of the switch. However, leadership has discussed it since with acting manager, so it’s no longer a surprise. To me it just seems like an unnecessary power move, aside from the space issue (the difference between the two office spaces can’t be more than a few feet). But the idea of di

Comment: He was acting in that role for a while, about a year ago? He also has seniority on the team. There hasn’t been any on site supervision to the program to address office space in years - so it wasn’t an issue. That’s my guess...

Answer (score 1):

This situation cannot be solved outside the place. You need to get the people working on that floor, explain the situation, all pro's and con's, ask for feedback. You need to also know the number of meetings which are expected to take, place, and the estimated number of participants.

Maybe it is possible to use a proper meeting room for meetings, and leave the floor untouched.

You might still need to upset a few people by not going their way, but at least you show that you try to be "the nice guy" and you care for more than yourself.

Comment: Note that it might be appropriate that OP just has to claim the bigger corner office to establish himself as the manager. Of course this doesn't change the basis of your answer, OPs question can't be answered without company context.